# how to record information for installed extension using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have installed extension in firefox browser.  I have started the selenium IDE.  When I click on icon for extension, a login window gets opened, but it is not getting recorded in selenium.  Also when I type email ID & password, nothing is getting recorded in selenium.  How to solve?  Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the top right red circle record button is clicked?

You can also try File > New Test Case

then Actions > Record

Comment: hi alquatoun,yes red circle record button is clicked,but nothing is getting recorded.Help me.

Comment: what version of Firefox are you using?